# Calculate the Average of multiple Averages

Tags: crystal-reports, average

I need to calculate the average of multiple averages within Crystal Reports with specific criteria. My report averages scores for multiple courses by a developer. I need to get the average value of the averages, based on the number of courses for that developer:

```
Course 1 10 responses         Course 1 Average 42.86
Course 2 12 responses         Course 2 Average 39.36
```

How do I create a formula that give me the correct Average `((42.86 + 39.36)/2)` of those two courses for that developer?

Answer (score 0):

Try a Running Total for that field, where the *Type of Summary* is set to "Average". Specify that the total should reset every time it reaches a new Developer group.

[image]

Sometimes Crystal won't let you summarize a summary. If it gives you guff, you can achieve the same effect with Shared Variables. Simply add each average in turn to the shared variable, then divide by a distinct count of averages. The final Formula field would look something like:

```
Shared NumberVar sum;
Shared NumberVar count;
sum/count
```